# Throwing from destructor behavior varies with and without TUI

Tags: c++, gdb, tui

I have modified the following *Effective C++ item 8: Prevent Exceptions from leaving destructors* so that there are not two exceptions propagating and hence a crash/UD is not expected here:

```
#include <iostream>

class Bad
{
    public:
        ~Bad()
        {
            std::cout << "Throw in ~Bad()." << std::endl;
            throw 1;
        }
};
int main()
{
    try
    {
        Bad   bad;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "Print This" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**Expected and Actual output:**

```
Throw in ~Bad().
Print This
```

Running gdb also gives the same behavior.
However running through gdb TUI makes the program crash at `throw 1`

This is reproducible on :

```
g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

**Question:** the machine instructions packed into the binary is the same irrespective of whether i run through gdb or through gdb TUI, does it mean that the way TUI is interpreting the instructions varies from the way gdb interprets?

Sameways, in the past i found different behaviors when the executable is run through gdb and run directly as ./a.out, and i couldn't understand how can the same executable give different results just with the way we run it

**Note:** The same isn't reproducible when run on g++ 4.8.5.

Comment: When you say "TUI" do you mean the standard command-line interface `gdb` program?

Comment: Also, stopping when exceptions are thrown is the *default* behavior for just about all debuggers. Perhaps whatever IDE you're using changed the default settings of GDB?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude gdb doesn't do that by default for caught exceptions, must type "catch throw" for that. But I have vague feeling that the problem here is that it happens in constructor of object in local scope.

Comment: Text user interface is what i mean by tui

Comment: Which C++ standard are you using? In C++11 destructors are nothrow() by default, and my compiler gives a warning about this code.

Comment: I didn't build the code with -std=c++11. If i build it without any std flag with noexcept it throws errors about noexcept(unlessi include the std flag for 11)

Comment: What is gdb version? How exactly does the program crash at `throw 1`? Is it segfault or something else?

Comment: *sigh*, I saw the gcc version and thought it was the gdb version. I'll delete my comment. (though the gcc version is also a bit old)